# Best tree type for store words by repetition

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I need to implement a data structure in c to store words by repetition in order (a struct woth the word and the number of repetitions), where the repetition of the word can increment or decrement.

I need to find the word that changed their repetition , and move it into proper position (there can be more of one word with the same number of repetitions).

I can't figured out what is the best data structure for this. I was thinking in a tree but i need to be able to change the word position by its repetition. So there is any tree for this kind of problem? I can't find nothing.

Any sugestion or idea of how to do this efficiently?.

I will be very thankful with any help. Thank.

Comment: What do you mean by "*change the word position by its repetition*"? Why would you change its position, and why would it matter?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is not to use a tree at all. Instead, use a sorted array that you keep sorted. Keeping the thing sorted is simple: whenever you increment/decrement a repetition count, you just need to reinsert that element at the right position which takes only as many operations as there are places by which you need to move the string (the same operation as in insertion sort). For incrementing the count, that's something along the lines of

```
//pos is the index of the string within the array
struct node temp = array[pos];
for(; pos + 1 < stringCount && temp.repCount > array[pos + 1].repCount; pos++) {
    array[pos] = array[pos + 1];
}
array[pos] = temp;
```

As long as the expected position adjustments are small on average, this is likely to prove faster than any tree based approach: It avoids building/maintaining a tree structure which requires a fair amount of code and is not cache friendly. The loop above only touches consecutive memory and is thus as cache friendly as it can be.

Comment: insertion in an array is O(n) and insertion in a tree is O(log n) why shouldn't the OP use a tree?

Comment: That is a simple idea but it is rather slow. Using balanced tree would be faster but harder to implement.

Comment: @rpattiso The operation is not just an insertion, it's a removal followed by a nearby insertion. And that's very fast with an array.

Comment: good answer. if the words only need to be sorted by repetition then the insertion can be replaced with a search and swap.

Comment: Ok i get it, but... I need an array where i insert N words by their repetition count, and need to be sorted. so... insertion sort? And then i have to be able to search the word and change its repetition count keeping sorted the array. This is not expensive in time?

Comment: Yes, insertion sort is the straightforward method to add an entry to the array. Of course, that's more expensive than the increment/decrement operations. However, if the new words have small repetition counts, you can optimize by sorting the array in descending order, so that the words can be added somewhere at the end of the array. Searching for a string is always worth to avoid, independent of whether you use a tree or an array. The most powerful technique to avoid searching for strings is interning them in a hash table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning and .../Hash_table)

Answer (score 2):

If you only increment or decrement counts then an array will be best as @cmaster answer suggested.

To build the array efficiently, have the array grow toward 0. since new words will have a repetition count of 0 adding a new word is just appending onto the end and with a generous allocation this is cheap.

To decide where to move an incremented word, you can search for the last word in the sequence with the same repetition count and swap. If the number of words  with the same repetition is small then using a linear search from the words current position may be best.

```
void increment(int i, Word *word, int n) {
  int j = i + 1;
  Word old = word[i];
  while (j < n && word[j].count == old.count) {
   ++j;
  }
  word[i] = word[j - 1]; // swap
  old.count += 1;
  word[j - 1] = old;
}
```

If that is not the case then you can do an upper bound search on the array and swap with the position directly before, which is logarithmic.

Note that the code was written assuming the array does not grow toward zero.

You will need a way to find the word in the array, a hash map may be best for this, that way you can still do swaps and only update two values in the hash map.

Answer (score 0):

Map will be good here.. Keep the word as the KEY and the counter as the VALUE of the map.. You can increment and decrement the counter value by accessing the work (being the key). In order to store whether it got repeated or not. You need a boolean value to store this information.

So, structure with `map<String,in>` and a boolean `isRepeated` should cater the issue.